# Stop .Net Remoting

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

```
    public static void StartService()
    {
        Hashtable t = new Hashtable();
        t["port"] = portnumber;
        t["name"] = "somechannel";

        channel= new TcpChannel(t, null, null);

        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(someRemoteObject), "somedomain", WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);
    }

    public static void StopService()
    {
         //what should I do ??
    }
```

`buttonStart_Click`: calls `StartService()`
`buttonStop_Click`: calls `StopService()`

It's obvious that clicking `buttonStart` twice make "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted" exception.

the question is how stop responding to remote calls without terminating the application.

Comment: This looks like you're writing new code. If so you'd better drop Remoting and delve into WCF.

Comment: What is the functionality where you are starting and stopping and restarting the remoting?  Why not make the connection for the lifetime of the application and just use one connection?

Comment: .Net remoting is an easy way to let services communicate and it depends what he wants to achieve if WCF really is a better solution to his problem.

Comment: WCF is pretty easy too. It has the additional advantage of not being obsolete.

Comment: the question is how stop responding to remote calls without terminating the application.

Answer (score 2):

How about you just set a flag the first time buttonStart_Click is called, and if the flag is set, skip the remoting stuff?

Comment: In addition to John Saunders answer, you could try to find out if the channel has already been registered. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.channelservices.getchannel(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try

`ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(channel);`